# ChatterBot Not recognised Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatterbot

I am using python 3.7.2. I downloaded chatterbot using:

```
pip install -U chatterbot==1.0.4
```

but the code doesn't recognise **chatterbot** but it recognises **ChatterBot**, but when ran, I get this error:

```
File "e:/PythonProjects/Projects/ChatterBot/Bot.py", line 3, in <module>
from ChatterBot import ChatBot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ChatterBot'
```

Why is this?
Full code:

```
from ChatterBot import ChatBot
chatbot = ChatterBot.ChatBot("Chatpot")

exit_conditions = (":q", "quit", "exit")
while True:
 query = input("> ")
 if query in exit_conditions:
    break
 else:
    print(f" {chatbot.get_response(query)}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `PyPi` entry for [`chatterbot`](https://pypi.org/project/ChatterBot/), the basic usage section says the following:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer

chatbot = ChatBot('Ron Obvious')

# Create a new trainer for the chatbot
trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)

# Train the chatbot based on the english corpus
trainer.train("chatterbot.corpus.english")

# Get a response to an input statement
chatbot.get_response("Hello, how are you today?")
```

So you should use `chatterbot` **and not** `ChatterBot` when importing the module.

Additionally, when using the `-U` flag in `pip install` it upgrades the package to the newest available version. So drop the flag if you want to install a specific version.